# Copy table with an extra column in C# with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables and their only difference is one column is missing from one of the tables. I'm getting the tables from two separate datasets. I want to move all data with an additional  column to the new dataset.

How can I approach this operation?

Comment: Is DataTable empty in target dataset.

Comment: Yes, i'm deleting all data before copy from target dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing this all in SQL and running the statement from C# if required.

Otherwise loop through one of the result sets and add them row by row to the other.

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO t1(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, NULL AS col3
FROM t2
```

or if you just wanted to SELECT the result (without updating the table):

```
SELECT *
   FROM t1

UNION ALL

SELECT *, NULL
   FROM t2
```